# How to update uncontrolled / readonly input value from parent component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple textfield (`<input type="text"/>`) component (child component) that should only show the value it gets from its parent component. It is `readonly` and the user cannot change the value.

My problem is that the textfield is rendered once with the right value but then does not update itself as soon as the value in the parent component changes. The value stays the same although the `render` method is called each time the parent component changes its `state` (check your console).

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/5334/) to demonstrate my problem.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `value` prop instead of `defaultValue`. [Here's an updated jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/5336/)

Comment: Cheers! How would you make such a textfield component more general so it can also be used to allow for user input?

Comment: It should call a `onChange(newValue)` event handler every time its value is mutated by the user, so that the input owner can update its state and re-render the textfield with the new value. In short, you're creating your own [controlled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html).

Comment: But then you have to use `this.state.value` instead `this.props.value` for the input `value`, right? That's my problem. I think it doesn't work to have an input field update itself and at the same time allow updates from parent component. It would be against the "single source of truth". I will have to propagate changes up to the parent. Anyways thanks for the initial help.

Comment: That's what I meant, but I guess you expressed it better :)

Answer (score 0):

`defaultValue` is only used on the initial render.
(source:https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2764#issuecomment-67890726)

If you replace `defaultValue` with `value` it works: http://jsfiddle.net/hnc7fobu/1/

(And it's ok since you have the readOnly attribute, you won't get this warning:
Failed propType: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.)

Comment: Cheers! How would you make such a textfield component more general so it can also be used to allow for user input?